# Measuring Switch State using PIC

Tags: pic, digital-logic, switches, logic-level

What is the best way to measure the state of a latching switch using a micro controller?
Keeping in mind the voltage level of the input to the switch is higher then the maximum voltage input to a MCU as show below:
[image]

I have attempted to solve this myself using the following circuit (a simple voltage divider) however i'm not entirely confident in my solution due to my lack of experience. Below is my attempt however I am worried that when switch is open the input appears to be floating, which could yield some incorrect reading?[image]

Answer (score 3):

This will work. When the switch is open, the pin does not float, it is pulled down via R2. A couple of caveats, however.

1. You need to ensure that the ground of the MCU is connected to the ground of the 12V supply.
2. The motor is an inductive load, and as such you will get voltage spikes when it is  switched off. To counteract this you should clamp the input to the MCU to its voltage rails (0V & 5V for example) using diodes - one with the anode at the MCU input pin and the cathode at the positive MCU supply and one with the anode at ground and the cathode at the MCU pin.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, you can employ an optoisolator.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2frpEp2.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The [FOD817](https://www.fairchildsemi.com/datasheets/FO/FOD814A.pdf) isolates any spikes from the motor, means you don't have to have the grounds connected, and keeps the input voltage to the chip within proper bounds.

Edit: Incidentally, note that none of these circuits actually measure the switch state, rather they measure the voltage across the motor. If you are intent on measuring the switch state, then you either need to add a switch contact or put some circuitry (such as a diode) in series with the motor (or use current or some other scheme).

The difference is that if you have a motor with a lot of rotary inertia compared to friction and cut the power to it, it will continue to generate electricity at the terminals for some time as the motor winds down from friction (and the load imposed by the circuitry). For example, my 8" tool grinder keeps its incandescent worklight lit for several seconds after the power has been removed.